# The View or layout moves up when the keypad is shown

Tags: android

I tried for adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"` etc in my activity manifest but it didn't worked for me. This works fine in activity but not in fragment. In fragment the views are coming up with the keypad.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txtsize_14">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and also put android:fillViewport="true" in fragment top view

Comment: you want to show these views or not

Comment: I dont want the bottom views to get up  with the keypad @jiteshmohite

Comment: @Devyani M Is your view maybe a RecyclerView or ListView?

Comment: try these it will work android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: Have you tried with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:fillViewport="true"` for Scrollview? @DevyaniM

Comment: yes my fragment is having listview @Goran

Comment: You can also try isScrollContainer="false" for your ScrollView. It is hard to answer without seeing your layout.

Comment: @Devyani M I'm having a simmilar issue. I have a RecyclerView inside a fragment. While the keyboard is being removed from the view(slide out animation) the same thing happens as you described, but not before.

Comment: This is not the answer, just a tip: based on documentation, there is no "orientation" argument for RelativeLayout.

Comment: try to replace relative layout with NestedScrollview